# Null exception at removing a child node from a tree view node

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview, nullreferenceexception

I have the following function to remove specific nodes from a tree view control

```
private void PruneTree(TreeNode tn)
{          
    foreach (TreeNode item in tn.Nodes)
    {                        
        PruneTree(item);            
    }
    if (tn.BackColor == Color.LightCoral && tn.Nodes.Count == 0)
    {
        tn.Remove();
    }
}
```

I call it on a treeview root node, but it throws `NullReferenceException`for the `tn` at `tn.Nodes`.

I don't expect a null item because I iterate the child nodes of a node and certainly they can't be null.

What could be the problem, I think as I remove some nodes from the tree, it affects the function.

Comment: @dotctor I know what is null exception, but how could it occur in this code!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you remove items, you break the enumeration.

To prevent this from happening, loop in reverse order like this:

```
for(int i = tn.Nodes.Count - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i--)
{
    TreeNode item = tn.Nodes[i];
   //....
}
```

This makes sure that you remove items with higher indexes first, so the enumeration will not break.

Comment: Thank you, I modified my question and the solution is again your answer, even if I remove the items recursively outside of the loop. (however the loop indirectly execute remove.

Comment: @Ahmad, you are welcome. I am not sure that I understand the last part of your comment.

Comment: sorry for my English, I mean we usually see such an error and solution when we directly remove an item in a loop, but my code do it indirectly. (it calls itself recursively and inside the function I remove the given item). But anyway the solution is the same.